# Django LocaleMiddleware permanent redirects

Tags: django

I want to be able to have https://example.com/ 301 redirect to https://example.com/en/ https://example.com/fr/ https://example.com/de/ etc depending on what the LocaleMiddleware determines the user's language to be (for SEO purposes). Currently it 302 redirects by default.

This was [apparently added](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19277) but I can't figure out how to do it. The documentation doesn't mention anything about it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LocaleMiddleware.response_redirect_class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware).

Comment: After much confusion I realised you actually meant [LocaleMiddleware.response_redirect_class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware) = HttpResponsePermanentRedirect (settings.py)